# Microsoft teams in a SharePoint modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, microsoft-teams

I am looking at including a Microsoft teams conversation into a SharePoint online modern page, a bit like the way you can add a Yammer feed into a SharePoint modern page.

Is this possible within a modern age as I cannot see a web part for Microsoft Teams?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no default webpart and as far as I know there are no announcements regarding an out of the box webpart. One way to go is to build your own custom webpart with SPFx, but there's no api yet to read converstations. However, it is on the roadmap.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Teams-REST-API-Support-for-reading-conversation-Threads-amp/td-p/200650

Comment: is there a way to embed it, using the Embed web part?

Comment: Not as far as I know.